# COMMIT , ROLLBACK db2 error

Tags: sql, db2, commit, savepoints

I got that message bellow :

> A savepoint cannot be set because a savepoint already exists and
>   nested savepoints are not supported.

I'm doing that query :

```
 P3: BEGIN ATOMIC 

         INSERT INTO GPRSD001.COOP(
              --  CCOOP,
                NDOCTO,
                ICOOP)
            VALUES (
                --ps_iPkCooperativa,
                v_xDocumentoCooperativa,
                v_xNomeCooperativa);
           COMMIT ;
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000';
              rollback ;
        --EXCEPTION
         --   WHEN OTHERS THEN
        --  ROLLBACK;
           --   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, (' GPRS6002 - ERRO: ' || SQLERRM || ' - ' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE));
        END; -->> Fim - Inserindo cooperativa <<--
```

How do i get rid of it ?  That error , its related with SavePoint right ?

Comment: How is this both `Oracle` and `DB2`?  What is the rest of the code, where the other savepoint has been created?

Comment: Acctually i didnt created savepoint on it . Im migrating Oracle scripts to DB2 .

This is Oracle Script 
`BEGIN
            INSERT INTO COOP(
                CCOOP,
                NDOCTO,
                ICOOP)
            VALUES (
                ps_iPkCooperativa ,
                v_xDocumentoCooperativa,
                v_xNomeCooperativa);
            COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
          ROLLBACK;
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, (' GPRS6002 - ERRO: ' || SQLERRM || ' - ' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE));`

Comment: And i have to Commit in DB2 , but i dunno how can i see which savepoints were created on DB2 and also see which  savepoint has been creating. 

Looking in my code , i didnt see anything reffer to savepoint or something like that.

Comment: The savepoint is related to Transactions.  You have a transaction sitting open already, or you have other code not shown that created a transaction, or something similar.

Comment: Edit your question to specify your Db2-version and the operating-system that runs your Db2-server.  You should always give those details because they can determine the answer.

Comment: Matt 

I created a new savepoint and I related rollback to new save boint has been created . It works .. i dunno how but works. I'll do some test to see how actually Savepoints Works . Thanks Anyway for you help . Have a good one .